# built-in function to construct a map given a sequence of pairs

Tags: clojure

when `seq` is called on a map, you get a list of pairs -

```
(seq {:a 4 :b 5}) 
;; => ([:a 4] [:b 5])
```

but when `apply hashmap` is called on the list, it does not give back the hashmap but uses the first pair as the key to the second

is there a built in function that returns a map when given a sequence of pairs?

Comment: (hash-map :a 4 :b 5) ;;=> {:a 4, :b 5}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `into`:

```
(into {} (seq {:a 4 :b 5}))
;; => {:a 4 :b 5}
```

Comment: thanks! its knowing these little things that make all the difference